# Bulk Import in WordPress on shared hosting environment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can any one share a strategy to perform  a bulk import of post on Wordpress which may last long for about 10-15 minutes? I have tried to insert putting in a loop, but it gets interrupted in half way throwing **500 internal server error**.

I have tried the same script in our local hosting and found to be working fine.
The problem is in shared hosting in which the they have put limits on resources.

I am looking for a strategy that do batch processing on a single click, in which each batch is processed after a specified time gap so that it does not put load continuously on server resources. If you have better idea, please share.

Comment: You wouldn't want to look into increasing your server timeout?

Comment: I am developing a plugin which is supposed to be installed by many clients on shared hosts( most possibly). We cannot ask them to go for a dedicated server as cost matters.

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. How about `ajax` calls within `timeout()`?

Comment: That seems like a never heard idea. Can you just specify what it is? You mean to say we should call the button click action inside from a AJAX function? I have done like that only.

Comment: Well in that case, are you even able to call any jQuery functions in your plugin? Have you included jQuery library in the first place?

Comment: Can you just give out an url to an AJAX example that you are trying to explain? That would  be easy to understand. If you google, you can find an example that you are referring.

Comment: Sure, you could have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

Comment: This is the one that I was looking exactly. Glad I am did using this link. https://pippinsplugins.com/batch-processing-for-big-data/